# Derivative of a peculiar function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given
$$N(t)= \frac{K}{1+(\frac{K}{N(0)}-1)e^{-rt}}$$ where $r$ and $K$ are positive constants, find the derivative of $N(t)$ with respect to time

This is the function, and this is what I have so far...

[image]

I'm not sure if I got it right, I haven't seen anything like this before, some help? An explanation would be very helpful.
Ps. So sorry for poor image quality :(

Comment: You need to wipe your screen

Comment: @MathMajor I'll just type it up lol

Comment: fixed your text

Comment: Oh thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Using the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{K}{1+(\frac{K}{N(0)}-1)e^{-rt}}= \frac{-K}{\left(1+(\frac{K}{N(0)}-1)e^{-rt}\right)^2} \left( -r \left( \frac{K}{N(0)}-1 \right)e^{-rt} \right)$$

Explanation: think of the function as $N(t) = \frac{K}{f(x)}$ where $f(x) = 1+(\frac{K}{N(0)}-1)e^{-rt}$. Then $$\frac{d}{dt} N(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{K}{f(x)} = \frac{-K}{[f(x)]^2} \frac{df}{dt}.$$

Remember, $N(0)$ is just a constant.

Comment: You have an extraneous $t$ in your $f'$.

Comment: @Kundor Thanks, was a copy paste typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying by

$\frac{e^{rt}}{e^{rt}}$